# How to include the number in the reference list using apacite

Tags: natbib, apacite, cite-package

I am using a template that uses the `apacite`, and define it as follwoing:

```
\RequirePackage{apacite}
\let\cite\shortcite %xx So get et al. with three authors the first time.
\let\citet\shortciteA %xx Ditto.
\RequirePackage{url}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\ackskip=6pt

\def\acknowledgments{\goodbreak\vskip\ackskip
\ifjdraft\large\else\footnotesize\fi{\bf Acknowledgments.}%
\hskip6pt\relax\ignorespaces}%

\let\acknowledgements\acknowledgments
\let\acknowledgement\acknowledgments
\let\acknowledgment\acknowledgments

\def\endacknowledgment{\vskip1sp}
\let\endacknowledgments\endacknowledgment
\let\endacknowledgement\endacknowledgment
\let\endacknowledgements\endacknowledgment

%C&G 8/1/2001 addition to process @pubdate & place \published after the rec, rev, acc dates
%
\def\@dates{{\footnotesize
{\rm Received}\space%
\ifx\@recvdate\@empty\@rcvaccrule\else\@recvdate\fi%
\ifx\@revisedate\@empty\relax\else%
; \space{\rm revised}\space\@revisedate; \fi%
\ifx\@accptdate\@empty\else
\ifx\@revisedate\@empty;\fi\space{\rm accepted}\space\@accptdate\fi%
\ifx\@pubdate\@empty.\else%
; \space{\rm published}\space\@pubdate.\fi%
\vskip-2pt}}


\def\@authaddrs{\ifx\authaddr@list\@empty\relax
\else
{\noindent\parindent=.15in
\ifjdraft\large\else\small\fi\authaddr@list\vskip1sp}
\gdef\authaddr@list{}
\fi}

\newskip\beforeendskip
\beforeendskip=9pt plus 2pt minus 6pt
\def\@sluginfo{\ifjdraft\else\vskip\beforeendskip
\hrule width 4pc\fi
\nobreak%
{\ifjdraft\large\else\footnotesize\fi
\clubpenalty=3000 \widowpenalty=3000
\parskip=0pt % plus 1pt %% amyh
\@authaddrs\par
\ifjdraft\else
\ifrog\else
%\vskip\beforeendskip
%\noindent\@dates
\fi\fi}}

\let\makecenterlines\noindent
\let\onecolumn\newpage
```

I am not quite familia with LaTex, so I don't understand. I have been using `cite{}` and `citep{}`, as defined above. But, I want to use `\numcite{}` and show the number in the reference list, e.x., as shown in [1]

[1] Amari, 2019.....

Unfortunate, I don't want to change much of the LaTex template, since I don't wanna mess up it.

Comment: `apacite` implements an Author/Year citation system as required by the APA. So it's fundamentally incompatible with numeric citation systems.  The code you've given us from the class isn't very helpful though; can you provide a link to the class itself? If you need to use a numeric citation system it might be sufficient to remove the `apacite` dependency in the class code and use a numeric scheme in your document.

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/agu-geophysical-research-letters-agutex-article/rnyzczmyvkbj

Comment: If you are using this class to submit to one of the AGU journals as it’s intended you must use APA citations not numeric. If you’re not using it for that purpose I would suggest using a basic class like `article` instead so that you can use the bibliography style that suits you.